# Regex: get string between last character occurence before a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with Regex.

I have this string: `\\lorem\ipsum\dolor,\\sit\amet\conseteteur,\\sadipscing\elitr\sed\diam`

and want to get the result: `["dolor", "conseteteur", "diam"]`
So in words the word between the last backslash and a comma or the end.

I've already figured out a working [test](https://regex101.com/r/uZ0oP4/1), but because of reasons it won't work in neither
Chrome (v44.0.2403.130) nor IE (v11.0.9600.17905) console.
There i'm getting the result: `["\loremipsumdolor,", "\sitametconseteteur,", "\sadipscingelitrseddiam"]`

Can you please tell me, why the online testers aren't working and how i can achieve the right result?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I've tested a few online regex testers with all the same result. (regex101.com, regexpal.com, debuggex.com, scriptular.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string

```
'\\lorem\ipsum\dolor,\\sit\amet\conseteteur,\\sadipscing\elitr\sed\diam'
```

is getting escaped, if you try the following in the browser's console you'll see what happens:

```
var s = '\\lorem\ipsum\dolor,\\sit\amet\conseteteur,\\sadipscing\elitr\sed\diam'
console.log(s);
// prints '\loremipsumdolor,\sitametconseteteur,\sadipscingelitrseddiam'
```

To use your original string you have to add additional backslashes, otherwise it becomes a different one because it tries to escape anything followed by a single backslash.

The reason why it works in regexp testers is because **they probably sanitize the input string to make sure it gets evaluated as-is**.

Try this (added an extra \ for each of them):

```
str = '\\\\lorem\\ipsum\\dolor,\\\\sit\\amet\\conseteteur,\\\\sadipscing\\elitr\\sed\\diam'

re = /\\([^\\]*)(?:,|$)/g

str.match(re)

// should output ["\dolor,", "\conseteteur,", "\diam"]
```

### UPDATE

You can't prevent the interpreter from escaping backslashes in **string literals**, but this functionality is coming with EcmaScript6 as [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```
s = String.raw`\\lorem\ipsum\dolor,\\sit\amet\conseteteur,\\sadipscing\elitr\sed\diam`
```

Remember to use **backticks** instead of single quotes with `String.raw`.
It's working in latest Chrome, but I can't say for all other browsers, if they're moderately old, it probably isn't implemented.

Also, if you want to avoid matching the last backslash you need to:

- remove the `\\` at the start of your regexp
- use `+` instead of `*` to avoid matching the line end (it will create an extra capture)
- use a positive lookahead `?=`

like this

```
s = String.raw`\\lorem\ipsum\dolor,\\sit\amet\conseteteur,\\sadipscing\elitr\sed\diam`;
re = /([^\\]+)(?=,|$)/g;
s.match(re);
// ["dolor", "conseteteur", "diam"]
```

Comment: Yes, escaping in the string. Shame i haven't noticed. But is there any workaround, or do i have to first double each backslash before applying the regex?

Comment: great! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
string.match(/[^\\,]+(?=,|$)/gm);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qA2qM7/3)